# How to get successive week number and year in java?

Tags: java, week-number

I am storing some data referenced with the week number. Now, I have two button to request for data. One for previous week and the another for the next week.And data for current week is fetched by default
I just finished making exceptions for the year end that I learned that there is week 53 too next year (2020). Now it breaks everytime there is a week 53. (It just skips week 53s)
Obviously, there must be a better way of doing this..
I just kept adding exceptions and following is the code I ended up with.
I am a noob, so please bear with the ugly logic.

```
LocalDate wks, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, wke;
try {
    week = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("week"));
    year = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("year"));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    week = getWeek();
    year = getCurrYear();
    flag = 1;
}
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now()
.withYear(year) // year
.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), week) // week of year
.with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 7);
wks = date.plusDays(-7);
if ((date + "").substring(0, 4).equals((wks + "").substring(0, 4))) {
} else if (flag == 1) {
    year++;
}
date = LocalDate.now()
.withYear(year) // year
.with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), week) // week of year
.with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 7);
wks = date.plusDays(-7);
mon = wks.plusDays(1);
tue = wks.plusDays(2);
wed = wks.plusDays(3);
thu = wks.plusDays(4);
fri = wks.plusDays(5);
sat = wks.plusDays(6);
wke = date;
System.out.println(week + " " + year);
heading = "<div class='row'>"
        + "<form action=\"";
if (week == 1) {
    heading += "javascript:setContent('/getData?week=52&year=" + (year - 1) + "')\" >";
} else {
    heading += "javascript:setContent('getData?week=" + (week - 1) + "&year=" + (year) + "')\" >";
}
heading += "<button type='submit'>Previous</button></form><form action=\"";
if (week == 52) {
    heading += "javascript:setContent('getData?week=1&year=" + (year + 1) + "')\" >";
} else {
    heading += "javascript:setContent('getData?week=" + (week + 1) + "&year=" + (year) + "')\" >";
}
heading += "<button type='submit'Next</button></form>";
out.print(heading);
```

function:  getWeek()

```
public static int getWeek() {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("w");
        return (Integer.parseInt(ft.format(date)));
    }
```

function:  getCurrYear() {

```
public static int getCurrYear() {
         Date date = new Date();
         return (date.getYear() + 1900);
    }
```

I have to print the dates of the days in the week, that's why variables of monday to saturday.

> I just want a function like below

```
function int[] getWeekYear(){
    return [prev week,prev week's year,current week,current year,next week,next week's year];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
YearWeek
.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) 
)
.minusWeeks( 1 ) 
.getWeek()         // Returns an `int` in range of 1-52 or 1-53, the week number within a year.
```

## Details

Never use either of the two `Date` classes. They are terrible, and are now legacy. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The [Answer by Renato](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59520823/642706) is correct.

### `YearWeek`

Furthermore, if your definition of a week is the standard ISO 8601 definition (week starts on a Monday, week # 1 contains first Thursday of calendar-year), then add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This library has classes extending the functionality of *java.time*. In particular, you get the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

Get current week. This requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" );
YearWeek currentWeek = YearWeek.now( z ) ;
```

To get prior or next week, simply call the plus or minus methods.

```
YearWeek priorWeek = currentWeek.minusWeeks( 1 ) ;
YearWeek followingWeek = currentWeek.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
```

If you want a date from a week, call `atDay` and pass a day-of-week from the `DayOfWeek` enum.

```
LocalDate localDate = priorWeek.atDay( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
```

You can interrogate for the week’s number and its year number (week-based-year that is).

```
int weekNumber = priorWeek.getWeek() ;
int weekBasedYearNumber = priorWeek.getYear() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The package *java.time* will give you a lot of satisfaction:

```
LocalDate.now().get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear())
```

This will return the week of the year (executed now returns 52), but the whole package contains everything you need, you have just to explore.